# Hadoop map process

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If there is a job that has only a map and no reduce, and if all data value that are to be processed are mapped to a single key, will the job only be processed on a single node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from Hadoop Definitive Guide, 6 Chapter, Anatomy of Map reduce job run.

> "To create the list of tasks to run, the job scheduler first retrieves
>   the input splits computed by the client from the shared filesystem. It
>   then creates one map task for each split. The number of reduce tasks
>   to create is determined by the mapred.reduce.tasks property in the
>   Job, which is set by the setNumReduceTasks() method, and the scheduler
>   simply creates this number of reduce tasks to be run. Tasks are given
>   IDs at this point."

Answer (score 1):

No. 
Basically, number of nodes will be determined by number of mappers. 1 mapper will run on 1 node, N mappers on N nodes, one node per mapper. 
The number of mappers needed for your job will be set by Hadoop, depending on the amount of data, and on the size of blocks your data will be split in. Each block of data will be processed by 1 mapper. 
So if for instance you have an amount of data, that is split in N blocks, you will need N mappers to process it.

Comment: correct, except that many mappers can run on the same node (a configurable number)